# Qt: change font weight

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, qtstylesheets

I would like to have my text in `QLabel` somewhere between bold and normal style and I believe that setting font-weight should be the answer to my problem.

**In Qt documentation, I have found out that there are two options how to change font-weight:**

1. From cpp side via: `QFont::setWeight()` method which accepts numbers 0-99

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#Weight-enum
2. From Qss style via: `font-weight` attribute, which accepts numbers 100,200,...,900

   http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#font-weight

I have tried both methods and nothing seems to work. I always get only normal or the ordinary bold style and nothing in between.

**Example:**

```
QLabel* test1 = new QLabel("Font-weight testing");
test1->show();

QLabel* test2 = new QLabel("Font-weight testing");
QFont font = test2->font();
font.setWeight(40);
test2->setFont(font);
test2->show();

QLabel* test3 = new QLabel("Font-weight testing");
test3->setStyleSheet("font-weight: 400");
test3->show();
```

In the example above, I have created 3 labels. One without any additional setting, one where I have changed font weight via `setWeight` method, and one where the font-weight should be changed via Qss style. But all three will end up being exactly the same.

I have even tried to make font bigger, enable antialiasing, or use different font but nothing helped.

Comment: Do you have intermediate-weight fonts installed or are you expecting the system to produce them by magic?

Comment: I really don't know

Answer (score 5):

The `QFont::setWeight` method expects its input value to be one of the `QFont::Weight` enum values.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#setWeight

The correct version:

```
QLabel* test2 = new QLabel("Font-weight testing");
QFont font = test2->font();
font.setWeight(QFont::Bold);
test2->setFont(font);
```

Also you have two errors in the QSS version. First, you didn't specify a selector for your rule. Second, the value of 400 corresponds to 'normal' font.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

The correct version:

```
QLabel* test3 = new QLabel("Font-weight testing");
test3->setStyleSheet("QLabel { font-weight: bold; }");
```

Comment: I have no problem with bold font. I cannot get the medium-weight font result. And the `font-weight: bold;` works even without the `QLabel` selector

Comment: Note, that like @drescherjm points out in the other answer, Qt**6**  keeps the same `enum` "names" but has change the ***values*** of those enumerations such that their integer value are now compatible with Qt *CSS-like* expressions of `font-weight: xxx;`. Also the number/range of those enumerations increased in Qt 5 compared to Qt 4.

Answer (score 4):

Use function `setWeight` like this: `setWeight(QFont::ExtraBold);`

```
QFont font;
font.setWeight(QFont::ExtraBold); // set font weight with enum QFont::Weight
font.setPixelSize(25); // this for setting font size
ui->label->setFont(font);
```

**void QFont::setWeight(int weight):**
Sets the weight the font to weight, which should be a value from the [QFont::Weight](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfont.html#Weight-enum) enumeration.

[image]

Comment: BTW: The weight values changed in Qt6.