# How to make a bold font to a QCheckBox

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5, qcheckbox

I have the following `QCheckBoxes` that will enable/disable alarms as shown below.

**The problem** I have is how do I change the font of the words "ON" and "OFF" only to make them **bold**? I am not sure how to combine a non-bold font with a bold font in the `QCheckbox`.

[image: cbox1]

[image: cbox2]

Below the snippet of code I have:

```
void FilterPCDInterface::on_disable123_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(ui->disable123->isChecked())
    {
        if(checked)
        {
            ui->disable123->setStyleSheet("QCheckBox {color: red}");
            ui->enable123->setStyleSheet("QCheckBox {color: green}");
            ui->disable123->setText("Alarms Zones Disabled: ON");
            ui->enable123->setText("Enable All Alarms: OFF");

            ui->enable123->setChecked(false);
            ui->enableZone1->setEnabled(false);
            ui->enableZone2->setEnabled(false);
            ui->enableZone3->setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    if(!ui->disable123->isChecked())
    {
        ui->enableZone1->setEnabled(true);
        ui->enableZone2->setEnabled(true);
        ui->enableZone3->setEnabled(true);
        ui->disable123->setStyleSheet("QCheckBox {color: red}");
        ui->disable123->setText("Alarms Zones Disabled: OFF");

        ui->enable123->setEnabled(true);
        ui->enable123->setChecked(true);
        ui->disable123->setEnabled(false);

    }
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

I went through the following posts to hep me sort out the problem but without success.
I consulted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455589/qt-change-font-weight), also I came across [this other source](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfont.html#Weight-enum), which basically is from the official documentation. But it does not explain how to concatenate a non-bold font with a bold one. 
It seems that the best way would be to use the `QFont` include but I am not sure how to apply it to the `QCheckbox` because I am not sure how to combine different fonts.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction on how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can't use multiple font for one widget. Another way would be to play with Brush but it's not seem to be accessible in QCheckbox, maybe you can do something like [this and use html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145611/how-i-can-use-sub-sub-in-text-description-from-qcheckbox) with `Alarms Zones Disabled: <b>ON</b>`

Comment: Also, you can use [CheckboxWordWrap](https://github.com/ThiBsc/qtCustomPlugins/tree/master/plugins/CheckBoxWordWrap) to do it directly in your designer

Comment: @thibsc, thanks for stopping by and reading my question. I will take a look at the html source you advised and will get back to you. :)

Comment: You find the solution ?

Comment: Working on it right now! Should be able to confirm in the next 20 min. Thanks for checking in! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `QCheckBox` with `QLabel` in a horizontal layout. So it becomes,

```cpp
QString labelText = QString("Enable All Alarms <strong>%1</strong>").args(status)
ui->whateverQLabel->setText(labelText)
```

```
       QHBoxLayout
             /\
            /  \
           /    \
   QCheckbox   QLabel(label)
```

Comment: But then "clicking" the label won't toggle the checkbox (as it does for a regular QCheckBox)

Comment: actually, it's extremely easy to implement: \n connect(&label, &QLabel::clicked, [=](){
                 checkbox->toggle(); })

Comment: OK, nice, never tried that. Looks like a good workaround!

Comment: Yeah, its simple to implement